# Is it possible to structure HTML inside JS to insert into HTML w/o using document.write?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a web app that inserts HTML via JS/JSON. I like to break things up by using white space in order for me to make navigating the code easier in the JS.

I have this:

HTML

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="placeholder">

    </div>
```

JS

```
$(passOptions.options).each(function() {
        var output = "<table id='placeholder2' class='table table-bordered'><tbody><tr><td><span class='primary-line'>Annual Power Pass</span><br /><span class='secondary-line'><a href='#'>Blockout Dates Apply</a></span></td>" + 
                                "<td id='powerAP'>" + this.premiere + "<br />" + this.preferred 
                                + "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        $('#pricing').append(output);
    });
```

Before the JS was like this:

```
$(passOptions.options).each(function() {
    var output = "
              <table id='placeholder2' class='table table-bordered'>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td>
                            <span class='primary-line'>Annual Power Pass</span><br /><span class='secondary-line'><a href='#'>Blockout Dates Apply</a></span>
                         </td>" + 
                                "<td id='powerAP'>" + this.premiere + "<br />" + this.preferred 
                              + "</td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>";
    $('#pricing').append(output);
});
```

But the JS version with the structured HTML wasn't working and I was also getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error.

So I reverted to the "minified" version since it works fine.

Is there another way to do this where the HTML is easier to view/navigate in JS?

BTW, this will live in Sharepoint where the user will be able to update certain parts of the app.

If you didn't notice, I'm building this using Bootstrap 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you continue to concatenate data unescaped into your markup, you're possibly creating invalid HTML and opening yourself up to some XSS attacks, all the while making your code unmaintainable.

What you need is a JavaScript template engine.  There are many to choose from.  I prefer [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/).  A lot of folks like [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

Example from the Swig documentation:

```
{% block tacos %}
  //...
{% endblock tacos %}
{% block burritos %}
  {% if foo %}
    // ...
  {% endif the above will render if foo == true %}
{% endblock burritos %}
```

See also:  http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/api/#run

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this ... easier for me to read ...

```
var output = [
  "<table>",
    "<tr>",
      "<td>",
      "Content Here"
      "</td>",
    "</tr>",
  "</table>"
  ].join("\n");
```

**`output`** is now a string built from the table and joined using `\n` for newlines when added to code.

Answer (score 1):

yeah javascript doesnt like those empty lines. If you want to format your html you could do it one of two ways:
1 - backslash the end of each html line

```
    $(passOptions.options).each(function() {
    var output = "\
              <table id='placeholder2' class='table table-bordered'>\
                  <tbody>\
                      <tr>\
                         <td>\
                            <span class='primary-line'>Annual Power Pass</span><br /><span class='secondary-line'><a href='#'>Blockout Dates Apply</a></span>\
                         </td>" + 
                                "<td id='powerAP'>" + this.premiere + "<br />" + this.preferred 
                              + "</td>\
                      </tr>\
                   </tbody>\
                </table>";
    $('#pricing').append(output);
});
```

or 2 - 
concatenate output:

```
var output = "<table id='placeholder2' class='table table-bordered'>";
output +=    "<tbody>";
output +="<tr>";
output +="<td>";
output+="<span class='primary-line'>Annual Power Pass</span><br /><span class='secondary-line'><a href='#'>Blockout Dates Apply</a></span>";
                         ....etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have you html as an html element with style="display: none;"

Give an id to your htmlElement.

```
var elem = $('#htmlElemId').clone().removeAttr('id');
elem.find('#powerAP').text(this.premiere); //Its advised not to use ids in your template. Use class instead
$('#pricing').append(elem);
```